# Error always shows up with no way to get rid of it (that I know of)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I always get this error and I have no idea how to fix it. (Unity 2019.4.12f1)

```
UnityEditor.EditorApplicationLayout:FinalizePlaymodeLayout() (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/EditorApplicationLayout.cs:76)
```

Comment: Is it the same as this? https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/error-when-going-into-playmode-with-maximize-on-play or
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-debug-invalid-editor-window-unityeditor-fallbackeditorwindow-unityeditor-editorapplication.395044/

Comment: Where are you getting this error? What have you tried? Is this a new project with nothing in it? What have you done to a blank project to make this occur?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your editor back to the default layout through the "layout" option in the top right.

If that doesn't work, you might have to reinstall your editor to fix it.